# ¿Cómo obtener variable desde $.each?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script-html-service

Estoy utilizando un API para conectarme a los servicios del callejero de la ciudad de Bs. As. y obtener algo que se llama "datos útiles" que incluye alguna información de la parcela que se indicó. El código es el siguiente:

```
function afterGeoCoding(pt) {
      if (pt instanceof usig.Punto){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '//datosabiertos-usig-apis.buenosaires.gob.ar/datos_utiles',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                  $('#'+k).html(v);
                });
                $('#datos').show();
              },
              error: function() { console.log('Error');}, 
              data: pt        
          });
      }   
    }
```

Y los datos, tomados del JSON, se muestran en el código HTML así

```
<div id="datos">
   <table>
       <tr><td>Barrio:</td><td id="barrio"></td>
       <tr><td>Comuna:</td><td id="comuna"></td>
   </table>
 </div>
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la variable de comuna por ejemplo para poder trabajarla previamente y poder enviarla a sheets mediante apps script? Actualmente solo puedo enviar el domicilio que se carga en un text input pero a estas variables no sé cómo leerlas. Así recojo la variable de el domicilio (b es el id del text input):

```
var elDomicilio = document.getElementById("b").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().domicilioNormalizado(elDomicilio);
closeIt()
```

Answer (score 0):

El endpoint devuelve un JSON plano

```json
{
  "comuna":"",
  "barrio":"",
  "comisaria":"",
  "area_hospitalaria":"",
  "region_sanitaria":"",
  "distrito_escolar":"",
  "comisaria_vecinal":"",
  "seccion_catastral":"",
  "distrito_economico":"",
  "codigo_de_planeamiento_urbano":"",
  "partido_amba":"",
  "localidad_amba":""
}
```

necesitas una variable en Javascript para asignar el valor

```
function afterGeoCoding(pt) {
      let comuna = '';
      if (pt instanceof usig.Punto){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '//datosabiertos-usig-apis.buenosaires.gob.ar/datos_utiles',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
              success: function(data) {
                comuna = data.comuna; // AQUI asignas la respuesta del API a tu variable y la puedes usar con appscript.
                
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                  $('#'+k).html(v);
                });
                $('#datos').show();
              },
              error: function() { console.log('Error');}, 
              data: pt        
          });
      }   
    }
```